# Show $B_t$ is a Brownian Bridge

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $T > 0$ be a fixed point in time, e.g. $T=1$.

Consider the stochastic process $B_t = (T-t) \cdot W_t + t \cdot V_{T-t}$, where $V_t \sim W_t$ for all $t \geq 0$.

We want to show that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian Bridge, i.e. we need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(B_0 = 0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 0)$ to show that the end value is equal to the start value.

How do I determine  $\mathbb{P}(B_0 = 0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 0)$?

My approach: w calculate $\mathbb{P}(B_0 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(W_0  = 0) = 1$ since $(1-0) \cdot W_t + 0 \cdot V_{1-0} = W_t$. Then we show $\mathbb{P}(B_1 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(V_0 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(W_0  = 0) = 1$ since $(1-1) \cdot W_t + 1 \cdot V_{1-1} = V_0$ and $V_t \sim W_t$.

Comment: Usually to show that a process, say $X$, is a Brownian Bridge, we show that the process $X$ is a Gaussian centered process and the covariance is $Cov(X_s, X_t) = \min(s,t) - st$ for all $(s,t)$ positive.

Comment: @Sesame Then this is incorrect?